Voice control command disambiguation
Voice control thinks there are two "Twitch" applications on my machine (see screenshot). I removed /Applications/Twitch.app (put it in the trash) and rebooted my machine in the hope that would convince OSX that that entry was no longer valid, but no dice - it still thinks there are two "Twitch" applications that need disambiguation. How do I get Voice Commands to reindex the available applications so this step is not necessary? I assume this is some OS-level reindexing that needs to happen, but the internet doesn't seem to know the answer to this question.
Update: As suggested, I've 1) emptied the Trash, and 2) invoked lsregister to try to nuke whatever file associations might be causing this, to no avail. The before and after output of lsregister -dump is below.
Mac-mini:~ benson$ diff before after4 | grep Twitch.app
> path:                       /Users/benson/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized/Twitch.app (0x1cdc)
< path:                       /Users/benson/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized/Twitch.app (0x1434)
< path:                       /Applications/Twitch.app/Contents/Frameworks/Twitch Helper (GPU).app (0x1f40)
< path:                       /Users/benson/.Trash/Twitch.app (0x1f44)

So lsregister only knows about the Chrome flavor of Twitch.app (where it used to know about the item in the trash), but Voice Control still thinks there is an /Applications/Twitch.app.

Selecting the entry for the item that used to be in /Applications gives this error message (as indeed it does not exist).

Edit again: Tried renaming the mentioned directories in ~/Library, again to no avail.
I see a sqlite db in the directory above this that

Did you empty the Trash?

Do you have a mounted TimeMachine backup? I had that problem once till I figured that out.

at IconDaemon Yes, question edited to that effect.
@SteveChambers If I do, I don't see it in the Time Machine setup (it shows no backup disks). I guess what it could be, somehow, is leftover migration data from when I migrated from a previous machine to this one, but  if that's the case I don't know how to delete that metadata.

When the Voice Control settings are opened, a process called localspeechrecognition reads files in these subfolders of the user's home folder:
Library/UnifiedAssetFramework
Library/Trial/NamespaceDescriptors

I suggest that you move these aside, then log out, log back in, and see whether there is any change. The second one is protected by TCC, so you may have to move it in the Finder rather than the shell.

Thanks for this suggestion, but unfortunately it did not do the trick. (edited my question to show the results)

I'm sorry to hear that. What happens if you select the nonexistent Twitch app in the dialog?

Updated the question to show what I see when I do that (it tells me it doesn't exist, as indeed it does not).

Please see my updated answer.

Sorry for the delay, no dice. (question updated) I guess I may just be looking at this never being fixed, which is about typical of my experience with Apple products honestly. Clearly this feature was not intended for desktop users.
